# How to interpret BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF BF results in R?

Tags: r, bayesian

Say we build the following table:

```
nnn <- 100
tib <- tibble::tibble(Completers = rep(c(1, 0), each = nnn),
                      Gender = rep(c(1, 0), length.out = length(Completers)))

expss::val_lab(tib$Completers) = expss::num_lab("0 Non Completers
                                                 1 Completers")

expss::val_lab(tib$Gender) = expss::num_lab("0 Male
                                             1 Female")

tibTable <- table(tib$Gender, tib$Completers)
```

Then, we do a Bayesian analysis:

```
bf <- BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF(tibTable, sampleType = "poisson")
```

The output is the following:

```
> bf
Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] Non-indep. (a=1) : 0.3471187 ±0%

Against denominator:
  Null, independence, a = 1 
---
Bayes factor type: BFcontingencyTable, poisson
```

My interpretation is that `BF10 = 0.3471187`, with a 0% error rate.

However, when I extract the BF result alone, the output is the following:

```
> bf@bayesFactor$bf
[1] -1.058088
```

My questions:

- What does this result mean (first output): `[1] Non-indep. (a=1) : 0.3471187 ±0%`?
- Given the code above, how/where can I retrieve it from (I don't seem to find it anywhere)?
- What does the result `-1.058088` of `bf@bayesFactor$bf` mean?

---

`sessioninfo::session_info()` extract:

```
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
 os       macOS Monterey 12.6
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0
 rstudio  2022.07.1+554 Spotted Wakerobin (desktop)
----
 BayesFactor            0.9.12-4.4 2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 expss                  0.11.1     2022-01-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 sessioninfo            1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tibble                 3.1.8      2022-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
```

Comment: `exp(-1.058088)` is about `0.35` so I guess the program does the computation on the log scale. that kind of detail should be in the documentation for the package.

Comment: @wzbillings: thanks for your comment and yes, you are totally correct! However, proceeding this way is rather strange to my eyes.

Comment: doing probability calculations on the log scale is way more "numerically stable". since the numbers aren't so small, there ends up being less error in the computer's calculations

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments of **wzbillings** these are the answers to the questions:

1. The result of the first output (i.e., `[1] Non-indep. (a=1) : 0.3471187 ±0%`) seems to be the Bayes Factor (BF).
2. This result can indeed be retrieved by issuing the `bf@bayesFactor$bf` command. However, it will be in log scale: `-1.058088` (i.e., `log(.3471187) = -1.058088`)
3. Therefore, in order to obtain the BF `exp(bf@bayesFactor$bf)` will have to be issued (i.e., `exp(bf@bayesFactor$bf) = 0.3471187`)

The complete code (script side):

```
nnn <- 100
tib <- tibble::tibble(Completers = rep(c(1, 0), each = nnn),
                      Gender = rep(c(1, 0), length.out = length(Completers)))

expss::val_lab(tib$Completers) = expss::num_lab("0 Non Completers
                                                 1 Completers")

expss::val_lab(tib$Gender) = expss::num_lab("0 Male
                                             1 Female")

tibTable <- table(tib$Gender, tib$Completers)

bf <- BayesFactor::contingencyTableBF(tibTable, sampleType = "poisson")
```

Console side:

```
> bf
Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] Non-indep. (a=1) : 0.3471187 ±0%

Against denominator:
  Null, independence, a = 1 
---
Bayes factor type: BFcontingencyTable, poisson

> bf@bayesFactor$bf
[1] -1.058088

> exp(bf@bayesFactor$bf)
[1] 0.3471187
```